# Start explorer from powershell after completely killing it with taskkill

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, windows-explorer

I made a script to run an old game which has grafic problems when explorer.exe is running. This script kills explorer.exe with `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe` and this works fine. But when I run `start explorer.exe` or `Start-Process explorer.exe` it doesn't restore my interface (taskbar etc) but opens a singe explorer window. Ho do I restore my GUI with a powershell command?

Thanks!

Edit: source

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "D:\Roms\PC\Anno\Anno 1602 KE\Anno 1602 KE.iso"
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
Start-Process .\1602.exe -Wait
start explorer.exe
Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath "D:\Roms\PC\Anno\Anno 1602 KE\Anno 1602 KE.iso"
```

Comment: I ran those commands and I works very well with me. Please, reedit your question and put the script source code.

Comment: Done, source added

Comment: What's exactly **1602.exe** program? The old game?

Comment: It's Anno 1602, a game made for win95 which still works with some tweaks (incliding killing explorer.exe / gui)

Comment: I noticed the 1602 in the exe is also in the name of the ISO file so I assumed it was a game exe

Comment: Which are the Win version running in your computer?

Comment: Cool it seems to be freeware https://anno-1602.en.softonic.com/ https://www.pcgamer.com/anno-1602-is-free-from-ubisoft/

Comment: @jluizsouzadev I assume Win10 since that's the tag

Comment: @jluizsouzadev Win 10 x64 Pro version 1909 (up-to-date).

Comment: Sorry, please, try to remove the parameter **-wait** of code line "Start-Process .\1602.exe -Wait", then, run the script again.

Comment: then the iso would be removed before I quit the game. So I cant. It would be bad to remove iso and restore explorer while still playing.

Comment: What if you taskkill 1602.exe, dismount, then run explorer.exe

Comment: Maybe taskkill explorer again before running it to make sure it gets killed if it started again while the game was running.

Comment: why should I taskkill the game I play?

Comment: I meant taskkill after you quit the game (to make sure it's not running in the background after you close it)

Comment: It's not, process explorer would show that. In the past I had a simpler batch script doing fine but after switching to powershell it broke. That's bas as I plan to extend this script and would love to work with powershell's functionality for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite the script like this:

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "D:\Roms\PC\Anno\Anno 1602 KE\Anno 1602 KE.iso"

taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe

Start-Process .\1602.exe 

Wait-Process 1602.exe

Start explorer.exe

Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath "D:\Roms\PC\Anno\Anno 1602 KE\Anno 1602 KE.iso"
```

Then, run the script again as **Administrator**.

References:

- [Wait-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process?view=powershell-7)

Comment: tried, same result. No taskbar showing up till I run explorer.exe from the run dialog.

Comment: Even after **1602.exe** to be closed?

Comment: jep. Wait-Process 1602.exe should wait till it has exited or do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, it has. **Wait-Process** does the script wait until to **1602.exe** to be finished.

Comment: so then yes, even after 1602.exe has exited.

Comment: Please, check that one out with **"taskmgr /7"** and tell me if it really exited.

Comment: I can't see it.
I sorted by name and can't find it in any cathegory (windows process, background process, apps)
Like I said in the comments under my qustion I made a similar script with batch and there it worked. taskkill, 1062.exe, start explorer.exe, pause. This worked fine but isn't as expandable as ps1 scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108099/discussion-between-jluizsouzadev-and-bdevgw).

Comment: @BDevGW Please check the details tab where it lists processes by filename.exe, some times programs still show as running here even if they don't appear in the "Processes" tab in Task Manager.

Comment: For example if you are running Firefox and close the window and when you open it again and get this error https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-already-running-not-responding it means there was a stray process in the background. When I get that error, I do not see firefox in the "Processes Tab" when I do see it in the "Details" tab. When I would close it in the details tab or taskkill.exe I would not get the error. (Details was called Processes in Windows 7 and Processes was called applications)

Comment: I'm always in details tab (or more exactly I use the much better and detailed process explorer for my every day use) :)